# Why aren't all images wrapping

Tags: css

Help me understand why only the last box is wrapping...

html:

```
<p>
  <div class='box'>
    <img alt="Red_box" src="/assets/red_box.png" />
  </div>
  <div class='box'>
    <img alt="Vertical" src="/assets/vertical.png" />
  </div>
  <div class='box'>
    <img alt="Blue_box" src="/assets/blue_box.png" />
  </div>
  <div class='box'>
    <img alt="Horizontal" src="/assets/horizontal.png" />
  </div>
</p>
```

CSS:

```
.box {
  float: left
}
```

Here you can see that the blue box is not wrapping, why?

**Update** with the sequence of events:

Window is wide enough for all elements:

[image]

Rightmost box wraps where it can:

[image]

Rightmost box wraps again:

[image]

Blue box doesn't wrap:

[image]

Comment: Show us the rest of the style. There's something else going on. Or maybe the parent element is still too wide? Is the blue getting cut off or what?

Comment: Because there's enough room for it to truly float left. The others are being pushed down because there's not enough room.

Answer (score 0):

according to your code, nothing should wrap. Do you have a width set to the parent of the p?

Comment: Yes, it will wrap, if you resize the window.

Comment: Well, it looks like the red horz one is wrapping - is the window not small enough? What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: See update for clarification. I'd expect the blue box to wrap just like the rightmost box does.